# UILabel - Multi lines are indented with firstLineHeadIndent

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, uilabel

I've been wanted to indent only the first line of a paragraph.
I've been using firstLineHeadIndent as following :

```
    let comment_message_style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    comment_message_style.firstLineHeadIndent = 50.0
    comment_message_style.headIndent = 0.0   // Tried to force other lines to 0 indent
    var comment_message_indent = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "HELLO\nTest1\nTest Long Line so that it will break without adding the new line char to the string.")        
    comment_message_indent.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: comment_message_style, range: NSMakeRange(0, comment_message_indent.length))
    self.commentMessageLabel.attributedText = comment_message_indent
```

However, whenever I run the simulator, the indent is apply on all new lines. (see screenshot below)
[image]

I'm using the last version of Xcode 6.1 and running my project on iOS 8.0.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Xcode is not able to recognize where is the end of the first line even if you used "\n" and I don't know why that's the case.

However the alternative way is to replace

```
    var comment_message_indent = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "HELLO\nTest1\nTest Long Line so that it will break without adding the new line char to the string.")
```

with

```
    var comment_message_indent = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "HELLO                        Test1\nTest Long Line so that it will break without adding the new line char to the string.")
```

the length of space = the total characters of your first line - 5.

This should do the work and your non-first lines will be indented properly and you don't have to add headIndent either.

Comment: unfortunately, your solution didnt work for me.
I had to remove all whitespace on both ends of the string.
Not exactly what I wanted but I'm okay with it.
Thanks for you time